# write() undefined behavior

Tags: c, file-io, file-descriptor

I've this code in which I receive a server response, check if it's a successful one, and if it is - create the file under the requested path and then write the response body to the file:

I'm testing it with the following URL:

> http://neverssl.com/index.html

So it means that I need to create a folder named *neverssl.com* with an *index.html* file inside.

I'm creating the file using the following method:

```
//full_path = "http://neverssl.com/index.html"
int create_file_under_path(char *full_path) {
    int fd, path_len = (int) strlen(full_path);
    char *curr_path = calloc(path_len + 1, 1);
    char *token = strtok(full_path, "/");
    strncpy(curr_path, token, path_len);
    while (token) {
        if (path_len == strlen(curr_path))
            break;
        if (access(curr_path, F_OK) != 0) {//The folder doesn't exist
            if (mkdir(curr_path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO) == -1) {
                perror("mkdir failed\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        strcat(curr_path, "/");
        strncat(curr_path, token, strlen(token));
    }
    if ((fd = open(curr_path, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0700)) == -1) {
        perror("failed to open file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    free(curr_path);
    return fd;
}
```

And then I write to it using write system call as follows:

```
if ((fd = create_file_under_path(url->full_path)) == -1) {
                            free_URL(url);
                            free(buf);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (write(fd, buf + header_size, tot_read - header_size) != (buf_size - header_size)) {
                            perror("write:\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

9 out of 10 times everything works fine, but sometimes even though that the folder and the file are created, `write` fails with the following message: `No such file or directory`.
I printed the FD when this happens and it's 4 as it should be.

I've no idea how to procced with debugging it any further and will apricate the help!

Here's an example where you can see that the file exists, the `fd` is indeed 4 and even so it enters the if statement:

[image]

Comment: `fails with the following message: No such file or directory` Please set `errno = 0` before calling `write`. I guess you are seeing uncleared `errno` from some previous call. `write` can return _less_ then the number of bytes request... you have to write a small loop, repeat the call for the rest of bytes. Only `-1` means it failed.

Comment: As for `how to procced with debugging` - check the actual value of return value of `write`. Use `strace`.

Comment: @KamilCuk It appears to be it, I meant to use the write_loop method that I have. Thank you

Comment: If `full_path = "http://neverssl.com/index.html"`, `if (path_len == strlen(curr_path))` will never happen.  You're building a file path, and ignoring the full URI syntax.  And will blow chunks on repeated `//` characters in the path anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> write(fd, buf + header_size, tot_read - header_size) != (buf_size - header_size)
> ```

From `man 3p write`:

```
   Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of bytes actually  written  to  the  file  associated  with
   fildes.  This number shall never be greater than nbyte.  Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.
```

*Only* when `write() == -1` then `errno` is set, otherwise it is irrelevant - leftover from some other operation. The number returned by `write()` can be lower than the requested number of bytes.

You have to write a small loop where you loop over the bytes to be written. When by it, consider handling `errno == EAGAIN`.